# How to make Wix DetectCondition for ExePackage always True?

Tags: wix, bundle, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.7

I'm making a burn installer with wix, and I have a specific ExePackage that I only want to run when uninstalling.  I'm assuming that to do this, I need to make the detectCondition attribute for my ExePackage always be true.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a working solution.

I used the built-in condition "Privileged"

```
<ExePackage Id="CustomUninstallScript" SourceFile="../../platform/win/uninstall.bat" Vital="yes" DetectCondition="Privileged"/>
```

The Privileged condition will always be true, as the installer itself is set to request for admin rights.  Therefore, this exe package will only execute on uninstall.